# Lore connections between Gold Dwarves and Calimshan / Dragons in Forgotten Realms Sourcebooks

Tags: dnd-3.5e, forgotten-realms, dwarf

What other sourcebooks exist for Dwarven lore, races, classes, feats or equipment specific to faerun beyond the Campaign Setting & the Races of Faerun?

Specifically, I'm considering a Draconic template Gold Dwarf Sha'ir, and trying to weave it into the lore. I'm looking for Gold Dwarf/Calimshan, Gold Dwarf/Dragon connections, or even just a bit more lore about them or their domains then what is available in the two books discussed above.

Comment: Is your lore search Edition-dependent, or are you okay with 1st and 2nd edition books as well?

Comment: Rubiksmoose thank you, okay! @theVagrantDog: as those are as far as I understand the historical past of the 3rd edition, sure!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done a little digging, and these are the books I'd check out if I were you.  I've separated them by subject matter and tried to put them in chronological order for you.

On Calimshan:

**Empires of the Sands**, a 1st-edition book, covers Amn, Calimshan and Tethyr.  Both **Calimport** and **Empires of the Shining Sea** are 2nd edition books (as far as I can tell, they came out within a few months of each other).  **The Player's Guide to Faerun** is, I believe, a 3.5 ed book, and discusses Calimshan briefly.

On Gold Dwarves:

**Dwarves Deep** is a 2nd edition book that is all about dwarves.  **Shining South** offers information about their primary abode, the Great Rift, as well as some gold dwarf-specific background information, and is even the edition you're working with.

On Dragons and Draconic Characters:

**Races of the Dragon** is a good read, and even touches on the difficulty of finding a dwarf-dragon cross-breed.  It then gives a few examples of draconic dwarves, so take that difficulty with a grain of salt.  **Draconomicon** is my personal favorite source for dragon-related information, and includes a couple of dragon NPC's that like to hang out with dwarves.  Technically, **Draconomicon** came first out of these two, but I decided to finish strong.

There are almost certainly other books out there that touch on your problem, but these ought to work for a start.

Comment: Player's Guide to Faerun is an addition to the Forgotten Relms Campaign Setting book (3e), is there any reason you dn't mention it? I recall there being information about Calimshan there too.

Comment: No, I mean, is there any reason you didn't mention "Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting"?

Comment: Uh, I guess I missed it. Well, signal comments for deletion after you read this one ;)